# CSV Parse out object c#

Tags: c#, csv

I need some help with parsing out a CSV we get it like this

```
OrderNumber,LineNumber,CustomerNumber,CustomerName,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,AddressLine3,AddressLine4,AddressLine5,PostCode,ProductCode,ProductName,Ordered,Left,Picked
```

we can have multiple lines for an order so we would get

- order Number
- CustomerNumber
- CustomerName
- AddressLine1
- AddressLine2
- AddressLine3
- AddressLine4
- AddressLine5
- PostCode

matching multiple times I need a way of parsing this out to be this structure

```
<orderDespatchRequest>
  <despatchDetails>
    <clientCustomerId>CustomerNumber</clientCustomerId>
    <clientOrderNumber>OrderNumber</clientOrderNumber>
    <dateDespatch>2015-07-01T00:00:00</dateDespatch>
    <despatchedDetail>
        <orderDespatchDetail>
            <lineNumber>LineNumber</lineNumber>
            <productCode>ProductCode</productCode>
            <productName>ProductName</productName>
            <quantity>Picked</quantity>
        </orderDespatchDetail>
    </despatchedDetail>
  </despatchDetails>
</orderDespatchRequest>
```

Hope someone can Help?

This is what I have got so far

```
public bool ExtractCSV(string file)
    {
        #region set up new dataTable

        dt = new DataTable("Header");
        dt.Columns.Add("OrderNumber", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Company", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("AddressLine1", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("AddressLine2", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("AddressLine3", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("AddressLine4", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("AddressLine5", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("PostCode", typeof(string));


        detailTable = new DataTable("Details");
        detailTable.Columns.Add("OrderNumber", typeof(string));
        detailTable.Columns.Add("LineNumber", typeof(int));
        detailTable.Columns.Add("ProductCode", typeof(string));
        detailTable.Columns.Add("ProductName", typeof(string));
        detailTable.Columns.Add("OrderQty", typeof(int));
        detailTable.Columns.Add("OutstandingQty", typeof(int));
        detailTable.Columns.Add("DespatchedQty", typeof(string));
        detailTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { detailTable.Columns["OrderNumber"] };

        #endregion

        #region Fill the table

        // read in the csv file
        string[] csvRows = File.ReadAllLines(file);
        string[] fields = null;

        foreach (string csvRow in csvRows)
        {
            fields = csvRow.Split(',');
            string orderNumber = fields[0].ToString();
            string customerNumber = fields[2].ToString();
            string Company = fields[3].ToString();
            string AddressLine1 = fields[4].ToString();
            string AddressLine2 = fields[5].ToString();
            string AddressLine3 = fields[6].ToString();
            string AddressLine4 = fields[7].ToString();
            string AddressLine5 = fields[8].ToString();
            string PostCode = fields[9].ToString();

            int LineNumber = Convert.ToInt32(fields[1]);
            string ProductCode = fields[10].ToString();
            string ProductName = fields[11].ToString();
            int OrderQty = Convert.ToInt32(fields[12]);
            int OutstandingQty = Convert.ToInt32(fields[13]);
            int DespatchedQty = Convert.ToInt32(fields[14]);

            dt.Rows.Add(orderNumber, Company, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3, AddressLine4, AddressLine5,PostCode);

            detailTable.Rows.Add(orderNumber, ProductCode, ProductName, OrderQty, OutstandingQty, DespatchedQty);
        }

        #endregion

        var query = from row in detailTable.AsEnumerable()
                    group row by row.Field<string>("OrderNumber") into grp
                    select new DataClass()
                    {
                        OrderNumber = grp.Key,
                        Details = grp
                    };

        OrderDespatchDetail detail = new OrderDespatchDetail();
        DespatchDetails despatchDetail = new DespatchDetails();
        string orderNo = string.Empty;
        string custNo = string.Empty;
        foreach (DataRow item in query)
        {
            DataRow found = dt.Rows.Find(item.Field<string>("OrderNumber"));
            if (orderNo != found.Field<string>("OrderNumber"))
            {

            }

            detail.LineNumber = item.Field<int>("LineNumber");
            detail.ProductCode = item.Field<string>("ProductCode");
            detail.ProductName = item.Field<string>("ProductName");
            detail.Quantity = item.Field<int>("");
        }

        OrderDespatchRequest request = new OrderDespatchRequest();





        request.despatchDetails = despatchDetail;

        return SendOrderDespatch(request);
    }
```

Could be well off the path with it.
Regards

Aidan

Comment: Are you expecting that someone writes the code for you?

Comment: No not at all I would like some hints on how to do such as try this or this I can read in the csv  store in to a dtatTable I'm just struggling with the logic of splitting it out.

Comment: If your able to read the values into a dataTable you should start looking at LINQ 2 XML. Which will allow you to write a query to output XML using your datatable as the source. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example the following should get you started.

Read the CSV File

```
        var rows = (from row in File.ReadAllLines("Test.csv") 
                    let item = row.Split(',')
                    select new  
                    {
                        OrderNumber = item[0],
                        LineNumber = item[1],
                        CustomerID = item[2],
                        Company = item[3],
                        AddressLine1 = item[4],
                        AddressLine2 = item[5],
                        AddressLine3 = item[6],
                        AddressLine4 = item[7],
                        AddressLine5 = item[8],
                        PostCode = item[9],
                        ProductCode = item[10].ToString(),
                        ProductName = item[11].ToString(),
                        OrderQty = item[12],
                        OutstandingQty = item[13],
                        DespatchedQty = item[14]
         }).ToList();
```

Group the data per order into a dynamic type.

```
        var orders = from p in rows
                      group p by new { OrderNumber = p.OrderNumber, CustomerID = p.CustomerID } into g
                      select new { OrderNumber = g.Key.OrderNumber, CustomerID = g.Key.CustomerID, OrderLines = g.ToList() };
```

Create the XML file (please note the output xml will not match your exact requirement, but this example should get you going).

```
        var xEle = new XElement("Orders",
                      from order in orders
                      select new XElement("Order",
                                   new XAttribute("OrderNumber", order.OrderNumber),
                                     new XElement("CustomerId", order.CustomerID)
                                 , from line in order.OrderLines 
                                       select new XElement("Line",   new XAttribute("ProductCode", line.ProductCode),
                                     new XElement("OrderQty", line.OrderQty))));



        xEle.Save("orders.xml");
        Console.WriteLine("Converted to XML");
```

Comment: Thank you for this helped me get to the fix.